# How to call sql search query in textwatcher?

Tags: android

i have a problem while using textwatcher to filter the items in my custom list view. Can anyone please help me how to call the sql query in this textwatcher? Sql query and my custom list code is shown below:

```
    public void searchValues(String mobile){
    try{
    open();

    String searchQuery = " select * from tbl_product where fld_mobile like  '%"+mobile+"%'";
    db.rawQuery(searchQuery, null);
    db.close();
    Log.v("Search_Query", searchQuery);
    }
    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        exp.printStackTrace();
}

}
```

Listview code:

```
     public class GridViewActivity extends Activity  
        {  
       DBHelper dbhelper = null;
      ProductAdapter adapter;
       ListView gridView;
       @Override  
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
     setContentView(R.layout.gridview);  
    dbhelper=new DBHelper(this); 

    gridView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);  
    //Add header of search bar
   LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
   ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, gridView, false);
   gridView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);

   final ArrayList<Product> list=new ArrayList<Product>();  

    try{
        ArrayList<Product> productlist= dbhelper.getEmployee();  
        Log.v("Query Check", "Working");
        for(Product product : productlist){
        product.getMobile();
        Log.v("Get Name:", product.getMobile());
        product.getPrice();
        Log.v("Get No:", String.valueOf(product.getPrice()));
        list.add(product);
        adapter=new ProductAdapter(this, list);  
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
   myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }

  public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
  }

  public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
   }

   });
```

Comment: do not use `BaseAdapter` / `ArrayAdapter`, instead use `SimpleCursorAdapter` and setup its `FilterQueryProvider`

Comment: can u please explain a little bit more. I ll be thankful to u

Comment: use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` when your data comes from `sqlite` database, do not use `ArrayAdapter` for that

Comment: please tell me i can use one adapter to list the getitem from db into listview and the same adapter for filter that listview?

Comment: yes, you need to use **one** `SimpleCursorAdapter`

Comment: i was using ArrayAdapter<Product> product is my class. How can i use simpleCursorAdater with my class?

Comment: whats unclear in `SimpleCursorAdapter` documentation?

Comment: i never used this before and i am new to android so i want to know can i use this with my product class??

Comment: just create it and use with `ListView#setAdapter` method call